# Why FileOutputStream can't count space between string?

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to store the string in a file. But in every time if i put a space between two string it always read first string.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class file_2 {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void File() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("./file_2.txt", true);
        // BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fout);
        System.out.println("Write a string:");
        String s = sc.next();
        char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(ch);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            fout.write(ch[i]);
        }
        fout.close();
        // System.out.println("Length:"+length());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        file_2 file = new file_2();
        file.File();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using Scanner#next() rather than Scanner#nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

The [Scanner javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says :

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace

And later :

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by Character.isWhitespace

In the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) :

> By default, a scanner uses white space to separate tokens. (White space characters include blanks, tabs, and line terminators. For the full list, refer to the documentation for Character.isWhitespace.)

So you can change the delimiter with `useDelimiter` or use `nextLine` to read the full line